# I need to solve this first-order system ODE using Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I have to solve this first-order system ODEs using Matlab.

y' + y - z - u = 0.

z' - y + z - u = 0.

u' - y - z - u = 0.

y(0)=1,  z(0)=0,  u(0)= 0

The analytical solution of above system of first-order ODEs is:

y = (1/3)e^–x + (1/2)e^–2x + (1/6)e^2x

z = (1/3)e^–x – (1/2)e^–2x + (1/6)e^2x

u = (1/3)e^2x – (1/3)e^–x

I have this code to solve it and plot the numerical solution I obtain using the ODE solvers and the analytical solution I have in the statement.

```
----------
clear
%options= odeset('RelTol',1e-5); 
options= odeset('RelTol',1e-5,'AbsTol',1e-7); 

[t23,y23]= ode23('functionB',[0 1],[1 0 0],options);
[t23s,y23s]= ode23s('functionB',[0 1],[1 0 0],options);

figure
ya =((1/3)*exp(-t23) + (1/2)*exp(-2*t23) + (1/6)*exp(2*t23));
za =((1/3)*exp(-t23) - (1/2)*exp(-2*t23) + (1/6)*exp(2*t23));
ua =((1/3)*exp(2*t23) + (1/3)*exp(-t23));
plot(t23,ya,t23,za,t23,ua);
title('\bf{Analytical solutions }')

figure
plot(t23,y23(:,1),'m-.',t23,y23(:,2),'g:', t23,y23(:,3),r);
title('\bf{Numerical solutions using} \it{ode23}')


figure
plot(t23s,y23s(:,1),'m-.',t23s,y23s(:,2),'g:', t23s,y23s(:,3),r);
title('\bf{Numerical solutions using} \it{ode23s}')

%legend('ya','ode23','ode23s',0)
%text(3.4,-1.7,'ya = -2sin(t) - cos(2t) ')
%title('\bf{Analytical and numerical solutions using} \it{ode23, ode23s}')
----------
```

And also I have the function functionB:

```
-------
function dy= functionB(t,y)

%-y+z+u
%y-z+u
%y+z+u

dy =[??????];

-------
```

I don't know how to write the solutions in the code of the function to use it in my code.

If someone can help me with this I will be so grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB documentation has [some good examples](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23.html#zmw57dd0e467512) about this.

You must rearrange your ODE like this:

```
y' = -y + z + u = 0
z' =  y + z + u = 0
u' =  y + z + u = 0
```

You then substitude `y` by `y(1)`, `z` by `y(2)` and `u` by `y(3)` and now you can write your function like this:

```
function dy = functionB(t,y)

dy = zeros(3,1);

dy(1) = -y(1)+y(2)+y(3);
dy(2) =  y(1)-y(2)+y(3);
dy(3) =  y(1)+y(2)+y(3);

end
```